# kubernetes - external firewall access

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have kubernetes containers who run many pods on environment A
and DB's that run on external environment without kubernetes.

I want to set my DB's firewall to give access to all kubernetes pod application 
that try to access it.

How can i set one IP gateway, that setting it on DB firewall, will always 
give access to all new/old containers pods.

Something like NAT.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering blind here since you're not giving much information about your infrastructure.

The first 3 scenarios that come to my mind are:

- If you have a VPN connecting both sites you could push your Pod subnet from site A to site B.
- If the traffic from site A is masqueraded through a public gateway, filter the IP of that gateway on site B.
- If both environments are on the same subnet, make site B part of the overlay network used by Kubernetes.

Comment: I have external DB on premise network and kubernetes container.
I want to give the permission to all my pods to have access to this DB.
How can i set permission on one single IP that will give access to all the pods that can always be created or deleted.

Comment: If your DB is external and all the rest is on premises, the client IP seen by your DB is most likely always the external IP of your edge router (second point in my answer), providing that you have a *single internet provider* and *static IP*. You can find this IP with a command like `dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com` or `curl icanhazip.com` inside you Kubernetes cluster.